# Distinguish between requesting HTML Partial and Full Layout for same URL / Route

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, rest, mootools, partial-views

At the moment I am writing the routing code for my MVC framework which is capable of rendering HTML partials (views). These partials can be loaded server-side or client-side (using Mootools HTML request). The layout of every page is then build from multiple partials. As I want it to be ReST compliant, each HTML partial (view) maps to an URL in a defined URL space, as follows (indentation shows the intended document structure):

```
...
/      
  /navigation
  /content
    /profile
      /profile/1
        /profile/1/message/
          /profile/1/message/1
          /profile/1/message/2
...
```

Now the problem is that I want people to be able to visit "/profile" and then not being shown the HTML partial, but instead the full layout. I was thinking about the following:

1) Creating a separate namespace / prefix in the URL for partials, for example:

- /profile for the full layout
- /partial/profile for the partial

2) Sending a custom HTTP header to request for a partial or no custom HTTP header to request for the full layout.

The first option would be more ReST compliant (cache friendly), but I am still unsure (and that is the real problem) about other options that might still be unknown to me.

Before I start implementing one of the above solutions, I've got the following questions:

1. What alternatives do I have to distinguish between requesting partials and full layouts?
2. What are the best practices to keep the client-side state / context of each partial?

Comment: I don't understand the exact problem. Given the URL hiearchy you describe you can make available the resource for a message at http://example.com/content/profile/1/message/2 and have the profile at http://example.com/content/profile/1

Comment: The problem is that I need to distinguish between requesting "example.com/content/profile/1" as the partial *without* the layout (without header, footer and navigation) and requesting "example.com/content/profile/1" as the partial *including* the layout (including the header, footer and navigation). This should be done in a cache friendly way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you request client-side, the server will receive the extra header HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH with the value xmlhttprequest.

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 
   strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
   ....
}
```

This is a reliable header to test for, rather than add a custom type.

Comment: Thank you. I just noticed Mootools is doing that, but it was stripped away by mod_rewrite.

But the problem is that using a custom HTTP header to get different content is not cache friendly. The cache layer cannot differentiate between GET /profile (with no custom header) and GET /profile (with custom header). Of course some caches might support it, but it is not something that can be assumed.

Then I just realized that I could just add an URL paramater like ?route=partial for requesting a partial, just like they usually use ?format=<type> to override the Accept header.

Comment: I see that Varnish can distinguish on the X-Requested-With HTTP header. For the server-side composed version (classic style) I can then use ESI to let Varnish include the partials. For the client-side composed version (ajax style) the HTML requests can be used to include the partials. In both cases Varnish will cache the partials for me. The only problem that remains is that most web browsers will not be able to make the distinction and may show the wrong cached content from their browser cache (the partial instead of the full layout including the partial). Thank you for putting me on track.

Comment: Another option is to alias a second hostname to the server just for the partial views, and then test for the prefix in your server code. A full page view would come from example.com/content/..., but the partial views from p.example.com/content/...

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 is definitely a better solution that option 2.  In a RESTful system we create new resources all the time to make up for the lack of methods.

Creating a custom header is a really bad idea.

Comment: Indeed. Depending on a custom header for distinguishing between representations will surely corrupt most caches. I just set up Varnish that will act as a single sign on server and a object cache using ESI (only used when layout is composed server-side). Now I can keep my MVC code as clean as possible. The Redis (NoSQL) driver and the HTML helpers are the only parts exceeding 20 lines of code. One rule I learned is that most older web standards are so well thought of that usually workarounds mean you are doing something wrong or at the wrong level. Thank you for answering.